# Избавляемся от плохого кода в Django!

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

Как можно улучшить код?

```
if request.method == 'GET':
    ...................
elif request.method == 'POST':
    raise Http404
else:
    raise Http404
```

Comment: Использовать [CBV](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/class-based-views/).

Comment: `if request.method != 'GET': raise Http404` и всё, а CBV сам по себе плохой

Answer (score 0):

```
if request.method == 'GET':
    ...................
else: raise Http404
```

Comment: спасибо большое, а что с CBV можно сделать?

Comment: покажите весь код

Comment: там 600 строк один метод, когнитивная сложность!

Answer (score 0):

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/class-based-views/

```py
from django.views import View

class MyView(View):
    def get(self, request):
        ...................
```

Comment: спасибо за помощь

Comment: @Илья если ответ помог вам, [отметьте его решением](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).